# Hapi catbox not able to connect to redis server

Tags: node.js, redis, hapi.js, ioredis

First of all, I would like to say that I'm new to Hapi so don't judge me hard.

I am following [this tutorial](https://hapi.dev/tutorials/caching/?lang=en_US) trying to set up server-side caching based on Redis using `catbox` and `catbox-redis` `npm` packages, and I get the following error:

```
{
  reason: Error: Connection is closed.
      at Redis.connectionCloseHandler (/home/yuriy/dev/sources/all/hapi-getting-started/node_modules/ioredis/built/redis/index.js:305:24)
      at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:300:26)
      at Redis.emit (events.js:210:5)
      at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:75:11)
}
```

As you can see it says that error is in `ioredis` (v4.14.1 according to package-lock.json) package which is dependency of `catbox-redis`.

I have Redis server running locally.

```
username@my-computer:~$ redis-cli -v
redis-cli 4.0.9
username@my-computer:~$ redis-cli 
127.0.0.1:6379> ping
PONG
```

Here is my `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "hapi-getting-started",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "src/index.ts",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "rimraf dist && tsc",
    "start": "rimraf dist && tsc && node dist/index.js",
    "dev": "tsc -w | nodemon dist/index.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@hapi/catbox": "^10.2.3",
    "@hapi/catbox-redis": "^5.0.5",
    "@hapi/hapi": "^18.4.0",
    "rimraf": "^3.0.0",
    "typescript": "^3.7.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/hapi__catbox": "^10.2.2",
    "@types/hapi__catbox-redis": "^5.0.0",
    "@types/hapi__hapi": "^18.2.6",
    "@types/node": "^12.12.14",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.1"
  }
}
```

And here is my `src/index.ts`:

```
const Hapi = require('@hapi/hapi');
const CatboxRedis = require('@hapi/catbox-redis');

console.log(`Running environment ${process.env.NODE_ENV || 'dev'}`);

// Catch uncaught exceptions
process.on('uncaughtException', (error: Error) => {
  console.error(`uncaughtException ${error.message}`);
  console.error({ reason });
});

// Catch unhandled rejected promises
process.on('unhandledRejection', (reason: any) => {
  console.error(`unhandledRejection ${reason}`);
  console.error({ error });
});

const init = async () => {
  const server = Hapi.server({
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 8000,
    cache: {
      name: 'redis-cache',
      provider: {
        constructor: CatboxRedis,
        options: {
          partition: 'my_cached_data',
          tls: {},
        },
      },
    },
  });

  await server.start();
  console.log('Server running on %s', server.info.uri);
};

init();
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong? I've spent a lot of time on this issue so any help would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Okay, it appears that there is an issue in [Hapi official docs on caching](https://hapi.dev/tutorials/caching/?lang=en_US) (Server-side Caching section). The solution was very simple but not obvious: I just removed `tls: {},`.

```
  const server = Hapi.server({
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 8000,
    cache: {
      name: 'redis-cache',
      provider: {
        constructor: CatboxRedis,
        options: {
          partition: 'my_cached_data',
          // tls: {}, <-- Here is a problem, remove this line
        },
      },
    },
  });
```

This is `ioredis` config params. From `catbox-redis` [docs](https://hapi.dev/family/catbox-redis/?v=5.0.5):

> `tls` - an object representing TLS config options for **ioredis**.

You can find more details in `ioredis` [docs](https://github.com/luin/ioredis#tls-options).